# Turn off audio in web app when iOS device is locked

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, web

I am building a web application with sound - when I run it on iOS (in a browser, mobile Safari or Chrome - I'm not using a native wrapper like PhoneGap) and lock the screen, the sound keeps playing.  Is there any way to detect from a webapp whether the user has locked the screen and to turn the sound off when the screen is locked?